# Cumulative distribution of X_{1} = min{X_{1},X_{2}}

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, order-statistics

So I have $X_{1},X_{2} \sim^{iid} Unif(\theta,1)$,
hence the density function is $f_{X_{i}}(x) = \frac{1}{1-\theta}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$

What is the cumulative distribution of $X_{1} = min\{{X_{1},X_{2}\}}$?

For what I undestand it can be calculated like this:

$F_{z}(z) = F(x_{1})F(x_{2})$ and the$f_{z}(z) = F'_{z}(z)$

Is this right? Can also $X_{2} = max\{{X_{1},X_{2}\}} $ be computed and how?

Comment: The density is incorrect: $\frac{1}{1-\theta}\mathbb{I}_{(\theta,1)}(x)$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to write the indicator function, I'm going to correct it

Comment: $F_{z}(z) = F(x_{1})F(x_{2})$ is obviously incorrect: $z$ is the argument of $F_Z$ on the lhs while $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the arguments of $F$ on the rhs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard textbook case:
$$\mathbb{P}(\min(X_1,X_2)\ge z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge z,\,X_2\ge z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge z)^ 2$$and$$\mathbb{P}(\max(X_1,X_2)\le z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le z,\,X_2\le z)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\le z)^ 2$$